# Google Docs Viewer Page, not opening csv files

Tags: csv, google-docs, google-document-viewer

Google Docs Viewer working for all other required file formate like doc,xls, pdf and so on but not opening csv file, it through an error "There was a problem displaying this image."

I want to view csv without any file conversion.

Comment: same here works for all other formats but not CSV, did you find any solution for this?